# Initializing a string with a lambda expression?

Tags: c#

I'm having difficulty understanding how this code actually works.

Look at this line of code:

```
private Guid DatabaseIdOne => Guid.Parse("e4d00000-7770-4e1b-8273-8e7afb12dd13");
```

and how does it differ to:

```
private Guid DatabaseIdTwo = Guid.Parse("e4d00000-7770-4e1b-8273-8e7afb12dd13");
```

As I currently understand it, the first line of code acting as a method where WHEN you call DatabaseIdOne, it then parses the string(?).

Can someone kindly explain the difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private Guid DatabaseIdOne => Guid.Parse("e4d00000-7770-4e1b-8273-8e7afb12dd13");
```

Is an [expression-bodied property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members#properties), note that it will in invoke `Guid.Parse` on every invocation (see [decompilation @sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCDMACciDCiDetE8QBwCcBLANwEMAXAU0QHEBXIgE0QBFKyAjMgZyoEkmAeQB2NALwA+OoyYA6AApkCfABQAiKgBYmABn36AtAHZTuw1qoROhgBxhj8O1WNkAZpwhgmTCPHUAlADc2LiEpJQ0DMxsHNx8gqJWiOIyzIrKapo6BkamxuaW1nYOTrYu7p7evv7BoTgIyFqIALKqAZj1iAC+sN1AA)).

```
private Guid DatabaseIdTwo = Guid.Parse("e4d00000-7770-4e1b-8273-8e7afb12dd13");
```

Is field with default value set to result of parsing. Note that first one is effectively read-only while the second is not (you can add `readonly` modifier to the field to fix that).

Another option can be a read-only property with default value:

```cs
private Guid DatabaseIdOne {get;} = Guid.Parse("e4d00000-7770-4e1b-8273-8e7afb12dd13");
```

Comment: Thank you, that was a very clear explanation.